# EmguCV Video Reading in c#

Tags: c#, emgucv

i am developing a project in which i need to load a video file from opnefile dialogue but i cant understand how to do that. After loading a video i also want to stop or pause the video for further processing.  i am using EmguCV 3.0 version.

My Code is Here.

```
OpenFileDialog ofd1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd1.Filter = "All Videos Files |*.dat; *.wmv; *.3g2; *.3gp; *.3gp2; *.3gpp; *.amv; *.asf;  *.avi; *.bin; *.cue; *.divx; *.dv; *.flv; *.gxf; *.iso; *.m1v; *.m2v; *.m2t; *.m2ts; *.m4v; *.mkv; *.mov; *.mp2; *.mp2v; *.mp4; *.mp4v; *.mpa; *.mpe; *.mpeg; *.mpeg1; *.mpeg2; *.mpeg4; *.mpg; *.mpv2; *.mts; *.nsv; *.nuv; *.ogg; *.ogm; *.ogv; *.ogx; *.ps; *.rec; *.rm; *.rmvb; *.tod; *.ts; *.tts; *.vob; *.vro; *.webm";
            ofd1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            ofd1.Title = "Please select a video file.";
            if (ofd1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                vCapture = new Capture(ofd1.FileName.ToString());
                Image<Bgr, byte> img = vCapture.QueryFrame();
            }
```

What to do next for collecting stream of frames.

Comment: Call `QueryFrame` in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example code from the EmguCV documentation:
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Camera_Capture_in_7_lines_of_code

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
...

ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer(); //create an image viewer
Capture capture = new Capture(); //create a camera captue
Application.Idle += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  //run this until application closed (close button click on image viewer)
   viewer.Image = capture.QueryFrame(); //draw the image obtained from camera
});
viewer.ShowDialog(); //show the image viewer
```

Which would make your code something like the following:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> img;
OpenFileDialog ofd1 = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd1.Filter = "All Videos Files |*.dat; *.wmv; *.3g2; *.3gp; *.3gp2; *.3gpp; *.amv; *.asf;  *.avi; *.bin; *.cue; *.divx; *.dv; *.flv; *.gxf; *.iso; *.m1v; *.m2v; *.m2t; *.m2ts; *.m4v; *.mkv; *.mov; *.mp2; *.mp2v; *.mp4; *.mp4v; *.mpa; *.mpe; *.mpeg; *.mpeg1; *.mpeg2; *.mpeg4; *.mpg; *.mpv2; *.mts; *.nsv; *.nuv; *.ogg; *.ogm; *.ogv; *.ogx; *.ps; *.rec; *.rm; *.rmvb; *.tod; *.ts; *.tts; *.vob; *.vro; *.webm";
ofd1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
ofd1.Title = "Please select a video file.";
if (ofd1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    vCapture = new Capture(ofd1.FileName.ToString());
    Application.Idle += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        img = vCapture.QueryFrame();
    }
}
vCapture.Start(); // play
vCapture.Pause(); // pause
```

You would then want to hand your img to whatever you're using to view the video.